# How to properly update the recycler view when I retrieve data from firestore

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am making a chat application with firebase firestore, I made a snapshot listener to listen to any changes happened in this function

```kotlin
private fun listenConversation() {
        database.collection(Constants.KEY_COLLECTION_CONVERSATION).whereEqualTo(
            Constants.KEY_SENDER_ID, preferenceManger.getString(Constants.KEY_USER_ID)
        ).addSnapshotListener(eventListener)
        database.collection(Constants.KEY_COLLECTION_CONVERSATION).whereEqualTo(
            Constants.KEY_RECEIVER_ID, preferenceManger.getString(Constants.KEY_USER_ID)
        ).addSnapshotListener(eventListener)
    }

@SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    private val eventListener =
        EventListener<QuerySnapshot> { value: QuerySnapshot?, error: FirebaseFirestoreException? ->
            if (error != null) {
                return@EventListener
            }
            if (value != null) {
                for (documentChange in value.documentChanges) {
                    if (documentChange.type == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
                        val senderId = documentChange.document.getString(Constants.KEY_SENDER_ID)
                        val receiverId =
                            documentChange.document.getString(Constants.KEY_RECEIVER_ID)
                        val chatMessage = ChatMessage()
                        chatMessage.senderId = senderId
                        chatMessage.receiverId = receiverId
                        if (preferenceManger.getString(Constants.KEY_USER_ID).equals(senderId)) {
                            chatMessage.conversionImage =
                                documentChange.document.getString(Constants.KEY_RECEIVER_IMAGE)
                            chatMessage.conversionName =
                                documentChange.document.getString(Constants.KEY_RECEIVER_NAME)
                            chatMessage.conversionId =
                                documentChange.document.getString(Constants.KEY_RECEIVER_ID)
                        } else {
                            chatMessage.conversionImage =
                                documentChange.document.getString(Constants.KEY_SENDER_IMAGE)
                            chatMessage.conversionName =
                                documentChange.document.getString(Constants.KEY_SENDER_NAME)
                            chatMessage.conversionId =
                                documentChange.document.getString(Constants.KEY_SENDER_ID)
                        }
                        chatMessage.message =
                            documentChange.document.getString(Constants.KEY_LAST_MESSAGE)
                        chatMessage.dateObject =
                            documentChange.document.getDate(Constants.KEY_TIMESTAMP)

                        messagesList.add(0, chatMessage)
                        messagesAdapter.notifyItemInserted(0)
                    } else if (documentChange.type == DocumentChange.Type.MODIFIED) {

                        val senderId = documentChange.document.getString(Constants.KEY_SENDER_ID)
                        val receiverId =
                            documentChange.document.getString(Constants.KEY_RECEIVER_ID)
                        val conversationId =
                            listOf(senderId.toString(), receiverId.toString()).sorted()
                                .joinToString("-")

                            for ((i, item) in messagesList.withIndex()) {


                                if (item.senderId.equals(senderId) && item.receiverId.equals(
                                        receiverId
                                    )
                                ) {
                                    item.message =
                                        documentChange.document.getString(Constants.KEY_LAST_MESSAGE)
                                    item.dateObject =
                                        documentChange.document.getDate(Constants.KEY_TIMESTAMP)
                                }

                                messagesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
```

Then I make another snapshot to listen to the chat collection and get the unseen messages count and display it in the UI

```kotlin
 private fun updateUnseenMesagesCount() {
        val unseenMessagesMap = mutableMapOf<String, Int>()

        database.collection(Constants.KEY_COLLECTION_CHAT).whereEqualTo(
            Constants.KEY_RECEIVER_ID,
            preferenceManger.getString(Constants.KEY_USER_ID)
        ).whereEqualTo(Constants.KEY_SEEN, false).addSnapshotListener { value, error ->
            if (error != null) {
                return@addSnapshotListener
            }

            if (value != null) {

                for (change in value.documentChanges) {
                    val document = change.document
                    val senderIdc = document.getString(Constants.KEY_SENDER_ID)!!
                    val receiverIdc = document.getString(Constants.KEY_RECEIVER_ID)!!
                    val conversationIdc = listOf(senderIdc, receiverIdc).sorted().joinToString("-")
                    unseenMessagesMap[conversationIdc] = (unseenMessagesMap[conversationIdc] ?: 0) + 1

                    for ((i, item) in messagesList.withIndex()) {
                        val conversationId =
                            listOf(item.senderId.toString(), item.receiverId.toString()).sorted()
                                .joinToString("-")
                        for (map in unseenMessagesMap) {
                            if (map.key == conversationId) {
                                item.unseenMessages = map.value
                                messagesAdapter.notifyItemChanged(i)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

I call both functions in the onCreate method

The problem is when a user receive a message the unseen message count doesn't update neither the lastMessage and sometimes the second item in the list replaces the first item with the updated values

I have tried a lot of things such as verify that the notifyDataSetChanged is not called in the same time twice ect...
I also asked Chat-GPT and bing but there is no answer